# Upgrading to latest Salesforce Apex API version number

Tags: apex, api-version

Our organisation has over 100 Apex classes, triggers and VF pages written over a period of 8 years. The versions of Apex API that we have used vary from 10 to the latest 40. Now we are trying to bring all our Apex code to version 40. Should I be concerned about any incompatibility issues as result of version upgrade? Are Apex API versions backward compatible? Are there any guidelines that I should be aware of?

Comment: Expect **exciting** changes to the results of any test methods transitioning from before v23.0 of the API.

Comment: You are in for a lot of fun. I say go one by one. Since I doubt your tests were written properly you will need to test the functional results as well. You will have to split out test methods, account for depreciated methods, and work through bugs, ahem...., enhancements that may or may not affect you in different API versions